# Adding Git Commit Hashes to Email-ext Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: git, email, groovy, jenkins

I'm looking to output the result of a Jenkins build into an email using Email-ext plugin + a groovy text template.

By tweaking the default [groovy template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-text.template) slightly (i.e., no code edits), I have gotten the output to look like:

```
* [] Testing default post receive hook script | Author: Dev One
  - File: README [Change type > edit]

* [] Script enabled | Author: Dev Two
 - File: README [Change type > edit]

* [] Custom Email Text tweaking | Author: Dev Three
 - File: README [Change type > edit]
```

I would like to add the following to the email:

- add the hash from git for each change/commit
- the output of `git pull origin <branch>`

I've looked at the Jenkins API and the Email-ext plugin, but being fairly new to the internals of Jenkins, I'm not clear on how or what I should be looking at. Any and all pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I've made some progress in this regard with getting the commit IDs. Code is as follows, and hopefully this helps others.

```
Build Info:

  * Build Result: ${build.result}
  * Build Project: ${project.name}
  * Build URL: ${rooturl}${build.url}
  * Build Date: ${it.timestampString}
  * Build Duration: ${build.durationString}

<%

def changeSet = build.changeSet
if(changeSet != null) {
  def hadChanges = false %>
Changes in this build:
<% changeSet.each() { cs -> hadChanges = true %>
  <%= cs.metaClass.hasProperty('commitId') ? cs.commitId : cs.metaClass.hasProperty('revision') ? cs.revision : cs.metaClass.hasProperty('changeNumber') ? cs.changeNumber : "" %>
    <% cs.affectedFiles.each() 
      {p -> %> [<%= cs.commitId[0..6] %>]: <%= cs.msgAnnotated %> | <%= cs.author %> | File: <%= p.path %> | Change type: <%= p.editType.name %>      
    <%}   
   }     
    if(!hadChanges) { %>
      No changes
    <% }     
} %>

<% if(build.result==hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) { %>
CONSOLE OUTPUT
<%      build.getLog(200).each() { line -> %> ${line}
<%      }
   } %>
```

Sample output is:

```
[030bce6]: Ready for template v1 | Dev One | File: README | Change type: edit

[d4a310c]: Testing git rev-list formatted email | Dev Two | File: githook | Change type: edit
[d4a310c]: Testing git rev-list formatted email | Dev Two | File: README | Change type: edit
```

Steps to configure this are:

- in `$JENKINS_HOME`, create a directory called `email-templates` -- this is the directory where the Email-ext plugin looks for scripts or templates.
- Create a file called `my-text-template.groovy` in this directory with the code above
- In the build's "Configure" option > "Add post-build action" >  "Editable Email Notifications" and in "Default Content", enter `${SCRIPT,template="my-text-template.groovy"}`

If/when I figure out the piece about adding the output of `git pull origin <branch>` into this email, I shall post it here.